# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. How do I fix this error?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to plot a graph for only rows with an if condition. And to the best of my knowledge, this is what I've done.

```py
b = pd.read_csv('Zlatan_ClubComp.csv')

print(b.head())

if (b['Competition_Type'] == 'League'):
    pp = sns.pairplot(b, y_vars=['Appearances'], x_vars=['Goals_PerGame', 'Minutes_PerGoal'], hue="Club")
    plt.show()
```

Zlatan_ClubComp is the csv file from which I get my data. I've run the code and this is the error I get,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Siddhardh/Desktop/Python/Projects/Zlatan_Analysis/PairPlots.py", line 13, in <module>
    if (b['Competition_Type'] == "League"):
  File "C:\Users\Siddhardh\Desktop\OiDS Project\Zlatan_Analysis\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

From the Googling I've done, I know that pandas take truth values of conditional statements as ambiguous. But, I can't seem to fix this.

Comment: The premise is flawed because if conditions can only be specified on scalars. You are applying a condition on a column which returns a column of booleans. Do you see why this does not work? Also, the answers in the duplicate should answer your question as well.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and for me this error resulted when the `df` did not contain the column specified for the `hue` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b = pd.read_csv('Zlatan_ClubComp.csv')

print(b.head())

b = b[b['Competition_Type'] == 'League']

pp = sns.pairplot(b, y_vars=['Appearances'], x_vars=['Goals_PerGame', 'Minutes_PerGoal'], hue="Club")
    plt.show()
```